# Merging and Clustering Rasters using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, classification, clustering

I have 3 rasters for three regionalized variables (r1, r2, r3). The rasters have the same projection, origin and cell spacing.

Can I merge this into ONE "multivariate" raster? (ie x,y,r1,r2,r3)

I would then like to then use a clustering/classification algorithm. My desired product is a 1 map with classified polygons.

I come from a SAS background and am new to QGIS.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing a "multi-band raster." These references may help: http://wiki.awf.forst.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Creating_a_multi-band_GeoTIFF and https://fromgistors.blogspot.com/2013/07/working-with-multispectral-bands-in-qgis.html

Comment: Thanks - I got my 3 rasters into one Multiband raster..